# WinRT zoom of image control by code if possible

Tags: image, windows-runtime, zooming

I am working at a WinRT application that implies some manipulations of an image at a WriteableBitmap level. On my page, I have ofcourse an `image` that shows the processing results. My objective now, is slightly different though, I would like to know if there is any way I could acces through code the built-in zoom in/out that could be achieved through pinch mode if on touch device on control + mouse wheel if on PC.

Here's a bit of my code where I've got the image :

```
<ScrollViewer  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ImagePanel" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I am asking this in case anyone might know if this can be achieved only because the zoom is very optimized and can be extremely useful :)

Thank you, any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ScrollViewer has a ZoomFactor property and a ZoomToFactor() method you can use.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had a hunch that would be it but I couldn't manage so I'd thought asking someone who really knows this. Thank you once again!